# Convert Json string to object List in angular controller MVC web application

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

Guys I'm stuck with something. I have to convert a Json string to an object list.
I am working on a MVC project and I'm in the middle of an API integration.

Here's the data of the problem. I managed to get data list(has a tree structure) object from a cloud api and converted it to a Json string in MY WEBAPI.

**This is the query**

```
            var textvar = (from avbH in avb_Hotels
                   join catRs in cat_Rs on avbH.categoryCode equals catRs.code
                   join rep in hotelRepList on avbH.code equals rep.code

                select new
                 {
                   code= avbH.code,
                   destinationCode = avbH.destinationCode,   
                   description = rep.description,                                                      
                   hotelstar = catRs.simpleCode,
                   checkIn = hotelBooking.DepartureDate,
                   checkOut = hotelBooking.ReturnDate,
                   name = avbH.name,
                   address = rep.address,
                   accommodationTypeCode = rep.accommodationTypeCode,
                   minRate = (int)Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(avbH.minRate) * rates),
                   images = "http://photos.hotelbeds.com/giata/" + rep.imagepath,
                   rooms = avbH.rooms,
                   ratecomment = avbH.ratecomment,
                  });
```

This is the converting part and I returned it as a string to the webUI.

```
     result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(textvar2, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);// then returns result
```

I need to convert this again to a object tree in the angular controller of my webUI.
I tried angular.fromJson but it doesn't work

```
 app.service("APIService", function($http) {
this.hotelavailability = function(sub) {
    return $http({
        method: "post",
        data: sub,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;text/plain",
        timeout:30000,
        url: "/api/HotelBooking/Availability"

    });
}

app.controller("APIController", function ($scope, $window, $http, filterFilter, APIService, States) {


    var getAll = "";
    getAll = APIService.hotelavailability(sub);


    getAll.then(function (d) { // d has the returning Json string
        console.log("Succss");
        $scope.hotels = angular.fromJson(d.data); //deserialization<-- This doesnt work         
        console.log($scope.hotels);
        $scope.respData = angular.fromJson(d.data);
      }
```

[This is d(returning Json string from the webAPI)](https://codepen.io/IsuruNavoda/pen/wpgGBb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getAll.then(function (d) { // d has the returning Json string
    console.log("Succss");
    $scope.hotels = angular.fromJson(d.data);         
    $scope.hotellist = angular.fromJson($scope.hotels); 
}
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks alot! :D